# Popup Text Input Box in C++ with OpenGL

Tags: c++, input, textbox

I am trying to create a simple popup box that appears when my C++ program starts that will allow the user to enter the width, height, and length of a cube that will then be displayed in a separate window.  I have been searching for a very long time, and I have yet to find a solution that will allow me to do this.  Can this be done using C++, OpenGL, and GLUT?  Or do I need another library to allow me to do this.

Thank you.

Jordan

Edit: I am programming a cross-platform program and cannot use Win32 to accomplish this, nor any other Window-specific function.

Comment: There are cross-platform GUIs you could download. CEGUI is the one that I use.

Answer (score 1):

What are you are looking for is a [graphical user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface).

There are many libraries available that interface with various input methods (for keyboard and mouse) and provide graphical output. Each one has it's own *model*.
There are various models, but the most common one is *hierarchical*.

If you are looking for a learning experience, I suggest you do some Googling on how to make your own GUI.

If you are simply looking for a convenient library that does the hard-yards for you, I strongly recommended [AntTweakBar](http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools%3aanttweakbar):

> AntTweakBar is a small and easy-to-use C/C++ library that allows programmers to quickly add a light and intuitive graphical user interface into graphic applications based on OpenGL, DirectX 9, DirectX 10 or DirectX 11 to interactively tweak parameters on-screen.
> ...
> AntTweakBar works with GNU/Linux, Windows and OSX

It was designed not as a monolithic batteries-included do-all library (such as [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), another alternative), but as a simple and lightweight tweaking interface (hence the name).

There are [several examples available](http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools%3aanttweakbar%3aexamples#twsimpleglut) and it's API is quite simple, so it should be reasonably easy to pick up.

There's also [GWEN](http://code.google.com/p/gwen/). It is not a well known library, but I find it extremely versatile and easy to use.

> Facts
> - Coded in C++
> - Fully Namespaced
> - All standard window controls
> - Behaves like you'd expect
> - Lightweight (No XML readers, no font loaders/renderers, no texture loaders - your engine should be doing all this stuff!)
> - Easy to integrate (comes with renderers for Windows GDI, Allegro, OpenGL, DirectX and SFML)
> - Totally portable & cross platform
> - Doesn't need RTTI
> - Released under a "do whatever you want" MIT license.

**Opinionated note:** I prefer [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) over GLUT. It provides a nicer model, and is still in active development (unlike GLUT which has not been updated in a significantly long time). At least use [freeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I will look into all of the links you provided and do some more research and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another external gui library to do it. If you're doing it for windows, MFC is a good option. Or check library [OpenGL User Interface Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLUI).It's cross platform.

[Here some libraries](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/windowtoolkits/)

[Maybe this link helps you](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_mvc.html)

Comment: I also find this question, maybe it helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211018/what-is-the-best-free-cross-platform-opengl-gui-library-for-a-video-game

Answer (score 0):

Your statement saying that you wish to have a popup box implies your wish to use the underlying windowing system, regardless of the OS.
If you want to be cross-platform, there are quite a few libraries you can use that either emulate or actually use the underlying windowing system, such as [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).

If using such a library is not an option, you can always use the OpenGL window to draw text and emulate your popup yourself, but that's a bit more work, imo.